# Published Google sheet value does not match with excel pivot value

Tags: excel, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I published my google sheet though web and viewed in excel. I made a pivot table in excel using the data but some cells does not match w/ the original.  I have tried using formula in google sheet since the value reflected on the pivot is rounded off to the nearest ones

Comment: why not using directly pivot table in google sheets?

Comment: Control the rounding using rounddown() or roundup().

Comment: The date reflected in excel is rounded not just the pivot.

Comment: The google sheet is used by us using only 1 account at any given time.

Comment: What date? Perhaps you need to show a clear example of before and after.

Comment: Apologies, typo.  It's data rather than date